# Converting NSString to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, casting, nsstring, nsarray, nsobject

I am very new to Objective-C and I am having problem dealing with NSArray.

I have a class which looks like this

```
@interface Tuple : NSObject
{
    NSObject* dataKey;
    NSObject* dataValue;
    NSString* dataType;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSObject* dataKey;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSObject* dataValue;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* dataType;

- (id) initWithKey:(NSObject*)dKey 
          type:(NSString*)dType 
         value:(NSObject*)dValue;
- (NSString*) description;

- (NSString*)   getValueInString; 
- (BOOL)        getValueInBoolean; 
- (NSString*)   getAnswerValueInString; 
- (NSArray*)    getAnswerValueInArray;
@end
```

and this is my getAnswerValueInArray method

```
- (NSArray*) getAnswerValueInArray
{
    NSLog(@"%@",dataValue);
    NSArray* value = (NSArray*)dataValue;
    if ([dataType isEqualToString:@"vague"] == NO) {
        return value;  
    }
 return nil;
}
```

Return value looks like this
     **(     'KEY: 0\tTYPE: string\tVALUE = p1\n',     'KEY: 2\tTYPE: string\tVALUE = p4\n' )**

But when i try to loop though the array, something like

```
for (int a=0; a<value.count; a++)
```

I get the error below. Also , I tried [value objectAtIndes:0] and gave me the same (String) error. My guess is that somehow my array is not really an array but a string and therefore its throwing errors when i use array methods. But i don't understand why and how can i fix this to get an actual array.

2013-02-16 14:46:52.222 [3334:907] -[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x210b6e20

-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c5e7a70

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In the for loop `value` is a `NSString`. Show how the for loop gets it's value, that is the connection between the `getAnswerValueInArray` method and the for loop.

Comment: Hi Zaph, 
Thanks for the reply. I use something like this.                   NSArray *selectedAnswer = [qtn.getAnswer getAnswerValueInArray] ; if (selectedAnser != nil) {(for int a=0;a<selectedAnswer.count;a++)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not dealing with an array, you're dealing with a string. Objective-C is a little off the beaten track because objects are typeless but pointers are typed. Merely assigning an object to a pointer doesn't change its type or anything else about it (retain count aside).

It doesn't seem to me to be particularly clear what grammar you expect your string to have and therefore why you expect parsing to be built in so I'm not really able to say much more.

Comment: Hi Tommy, in that case is do i have to manually break down the string in order to get items inside it ?

Comment: To answer for Tommy, yes.  You need to manually break down the string if you want there to be more than one item in the array which come from the same string.  You can the use: `value = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:string1, string2, string3..., nil];`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to parse the string to create an array before attempting to access components within it. One way to get started would be to use the `NSString` methods [componentsSeparatedByString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a) or [componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet%3a). These methods each return an array of strings generated from the receiver by splitting it at the specified string or characters.